# Legendas ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho este gráfico criado pela função geom_bar():

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de separar as duas caixas onde são plotadas a fill, 
da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço isso? qual parâmetro da função theme() posso utilizar para resolver esse problema?

Comment: Experimente `theme(legend.key = element_rect(size = 10))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O atributo `legend.key.size` muda um pouco a distância entre os elementos.
Veja se serve para você:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(
    legend.key.size = unit(3, 'lines')
    )
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32277045/3297472) a referência em inglês.